# Extract items from string and assign them to variables

Tags: php, explode

I need to use php and extract the items from the string and assign them to variables.

```
$string = "76305203 ;124400884 ;109263187 ;current ;18.44";
```

How can I get:

```
$var1 = 76305203
$var2 = 124400884
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create variables use [list()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php)

```
<?php

$string = "76305203 ;124400884 ;109263187 ;current ;18.44";

list($var1,$var2) = explode(';', $string);

echo $var1;

echo PHP_EOL;

echo $var2;
```

Output:- https://eval.in/928536

Or use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to get array and use that array

```
<?php

$string = "76305203 ;124400884 ;109263187 ;current ;18.44";

$array = explode(';', $string);

echo $array[0];

echo PHP_EOL;

echo $array[1];
```

Output:-https://eval.in/928537